# Excel number sequence problem. Increment every 50 with a loop from 1 to 50

Tags: excel

I have to create in excel a sequence of numbers.

They start with a static 9900 then increment by 1 every 50 starting from 14000, then at the end I need to loop from 01 to 50.

Here is an example

```
99001400001
99001400002
99001400003
...
99001400050
```

---

```
99001400101
99001400102
99001400103
...
99001400150
```

---

```
99001400201
99001400202
99001400203
...
99001400250
```

I have got so far:

="9900"&INT((ROW(A2)-1)/50)+14000

It does the first part to increment by 1 every 50... but I cant get a loop from 01 to 50, then restart.

Any help appreciated

Screen Shot
[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to create 50 numeric strings? 2500 strings? What does "and then restart" mean?

Comment: I need to generate 10.000 numbers divided in booklets of 50 numbers. total of 200 booklets. All numeric strings start with the static 9900, then each booklet start at 14000 and only change after 50 numbers. 9900 _ (14000 - 14200) _ (01 - 50) . hope it make sense..

Comment: I edited my number examples..

Comment: VBA seems like a natural choice here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am addressing only the repeating patterns, not the fixed parts like 14000 or 9900.

In **A2** enter:

```
=MOD((ROWS($1:2)-2),50)+1+100*(ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/50,0)-1)
```

and copy downward.

**NOTE:**

This part:

```
MOD((ROWS($1:2)-2),50)+1
```

generates 1 through 50 repeatedly.

This part:

```
100*(ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/50,0)-1)
```

generates fifty 0's and then fifty 100's and then fifty 200's, etc.

Once you have verified this approach add the 14000 to the formula and pre-append the 9900.

Some snapshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the end, something like:

```
=9900 & (140000+MOD((ROWS($1:2)-2),50)+1+100*(ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/50,0)-1))
```

will match your posted data:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

I tried the same formula in Google Sheets and get the same result:

[image]

**EDIT#2:**

Wth the semi-colon as a field separator, the formula would be:

```
=9900 & (140000+MOD((ROWS($1:2)-2);50)+1+100*(ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/50;0)-1))
```

Comment: looks good, but I get a "formula analysis" error.. could it be that google docs has a problem with these formulas?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FlB59-M0foRbg87GwYGih5rXdKsQNNRbGhiT_j75NRE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @vance  **We are very close**  Let me investigate Google Sheets!

Comment: @vance  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I dont know why I get a syntax error. could you check this new sheet. I have given public access. 
 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19T5YhrJIhDgOOsuaV9XBUBuSd_wQVH88BB60kyONb6Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @vance    **I figurederred it out.**.  Your system need to use ***;*** rather than ***,*** as the field separator in formulas.

Comment: See my **EDIT#2**

Comment: unless I have misunderstood it, this should be the answer. I stepped away have not kept up with the dialogue until now. I arrived at effectively the same approach, but purely numerical `=99001400000 + MOD(ROW(A2)-2,50)+1 + INT((ROW(A2)-2)/50)*100`. It is not different from Gary's in any meaningful way. @vance - let us know if it works.

Comment: amazing guys. Life saver!!! both answers work perfect. Can I mark them both as answers? thanks a million guys.

Answer (score 1):

You could change it to:

```
="9900"&MOD(ROW(A2)-2,50)+14001
```

Comment: Not sure if I tested right, but this formula returns 990014001, 990014002, 990014003, 990014004, 990014005 and then it restarts over...

Comment: yep - that's what I understood was needed - 001, 002... 050, 001, 002...

Comment: Yeah, but yor formula works only for numbers 1-5, not 1-50

Comment: on my xls, it goes 1-50, but in any case i just saw the OP edit - mine won't do the page incrementing as is - i think Gary's is the answer

Comment: here is an example. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FlB59-M0foRbg87GwYGih5rXdKsQNNRbGhiT_j75NRE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the last part with the loop of 01 to 50. is missing

Comment: the digits on the B column need to be in the same numeric string in A

Comment: Sorry - i am jumping in and out of meetings and have not been able to keep focus.  Would `="9900"&MOD(ROW(A2)-2,50)+14001 + INT(ROW(A2)/50)*100` meet the requirement?  When I have time, I will drop by again and see. Hope you get there soon.

Comment: wait - just got your Google sheet open - ok, what about:  `=99001400000 + MOD(ROW(A2)-2,50)+1 + INT((ROW(A2)-2)/50)*100`